# Email sending approaches

Tags: email, azure, smtp

In my project have to suggest email sending approaches to my manager. As a part of design document.
Following are the approaches available. Kindly share your views on pros and cons for these approaches

**Approach 1**: Use third party SMTP
Pros: Readily available
Cons: Costs

**Approach 2**: Host own SMTP on Windows Azure
Pros: ?
Cons: ?

**Approach 3**: Using Public email Account
Pros: No additional cost or dependency.
Cons: Requires more effort in terms of designing and implementation.

Comment: Third Party should not cost much. We use SendGrid and it costs virtually nothing, like 10,000 emails for a dollar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does not matter what SMTP server you use because all your code needs to know is about the SMTP host, port, secure mode authentication and user credentials. And ofcourse your application should be able to connect to the SMTP host. If your application supports connecting to any SMTP, then no need to bother about what to use. You can very well use your own company's SMTP server or use public SMTP severs like Gmail, yahoo etc.

Comment: This is how we send e-mail from our Azure instances -- using the System.Net.Mail class and our company's SMTP server and an account we set up just for that reason. Works like a charm.

Comment: You're probably looking for this: http://sendgrid.com/windowsazure.html

Comment: downvoted for suggesting Gmail, you will get banned

Comment: How so? @Toolkit

Answer (score 13):

Approach 2 is not recommended by Microsoft, and I am also with that. The main reason is that the chance for IP Address of Azure datacenter to become blacklisted because of SPAM is very high.

Don't quite understand Approach 3.

The highly recommended approach (also by Microsoft) is to use a third party mail sending system, such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/azure.html). Microsoft & SendGrid are partnering to offer Azure developers free and easy way to reliably, securely and easily send e-mail message from the Windows Azure platform. Read more on the [link provided](http://sendgrid.com/azure.html). And this is the official reccomendation.

Comment: SendGrid's prices are outlandish... only 60 days free.

Comment: No, now it's always free, but it's only good to send email... not so good as an actual email address people can send stuff back to and you can reply to them, etc...

Comment: Good solution -- If you follow the steps to sign up through Azure, the free plan is 25k credits per month.  It looks like there's also a free plan for the public for 12k credits monthly.  I did not go through the sign up process for the later, but it advertises "No expiration."

Answer (score 4):

We use Amazon's SES service to send emails from [AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) to our customers.  Currently sending north of 3000-4000 emails per day.  Works wonderfully and is very affordable.

Comment: Me too. SES is easy, reliable and cheap.

Answer (score 2):

There is also option to queue emails before sending them using services like SendGrid or AWS SES. You should consider this option if your solution is dealing with high loads or if you do not like the fact that third-party smtp service is out of the Azure and out of your (direct) control.

Take a look at:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/10/08/adoption-program-insights-sending-emails-from-windows-azure-part-1-of-2.aspx
- http://www.AzureMailer.com (commercial solution)

Comment: Lack of disclosure that the commercial solution you have linked to is your own.

Answer (score 1):

third party is the recommended way to do this, take a look at:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/emailtheinternet-com-sending-and-receiving-email-in-windows-azure